# Why is the kinetic energy of an electron in a hydrogen atom at $n=2$ level, the negative of its total energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, interactions, binding-energy, virial-theorem

My textbook [1] says in order to determine the De Broglie wavelength of an $e^-$ in a hydrogen atom at energy level $n=2$, we can determine its kinetic energy first by finding its total energy from $E=-13.6/n^2$ then determine its De Broglie wavelength accordingly.

But isn't the total energy of the electron at $n=2$ refers to its potential and kinetic energy? How can we simply take the negative of the electron's total energy and call it the electron KE? This implies that at $n=\infty$ then electron's KE is 0; vice versa when $n=0$ then electron's KE is $\infty$.

References:

1. K. A. Tsokos, "Physics for the IB Diploma Coursebook" 6th Edition

Comment: Note that $n = 1, 2, 3, \cdots$. It does not include zero.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Note that the [principal quantum number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_quantum_number) $n\in\mathbb{N}$ cannot be zero.
2. Use the [virial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem). See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/125992/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: But virial theorem has to do with the system not with the electron. So how can be used?

Comment: The 2-body system (electron + nucleus) is reduced to a 1-body system because we work in the center-of-mass reference frame.

Comment: What if we work with multi-electron atoms? Would we neglect the motion of nucleus?

Comment: Ideally, we should not neglect the motion of the nucleus in the center-of-mass reference frame.

Answer (score -1):

It's a formalism from harmonic oscillator, so that when electron come from $n=2$ to $n=1$, it releases energy.

Also, without nature presetance of fields or confirment, $H$ can be ionized if you insist, there are just so many quantized value that one could take. Calling it KE is from hamiltonian operator. It's a correspondance with classical physcis.

Comment: What does "nature presetance of fields or confirment" mean?